# Upper bound on the number of lattice points on the intersection of a hyperplane and a sphere

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, analytic-number-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $R>0$, $\overrightarrow{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Consider the intersection $T$of $RS^{d-1}$ and the hyperplane $\overrightarrow{\alpha} \cdot \overrightarrow{x} = n$. What is the best known (asymptotic) upper bound for the number of lattice points in this region? That is, an upper bound depending only on $R$ that is valid for all hyperplanes. $T$ is a $(d-1)$-dimentional sphere in the hyperplane, so I would expect the bound to be of the order of the number of lattice points in $RS^{d-2}$, which for big enough $d$ is $R^{d-3+\epsilon}$.

Comment: An easy bound is to "tile" the intersection with unit cubes, forming a thin region with positive volume. One then estimates the number of integral points by geometry of numbers, which amounts to estimating the $(d-1)$-dimensional volume of the intersection, which is some ellipsoid. Doing this you get roughly $C_0 R^{d-1}$ integral points, which is what you would expect

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao that bound does not seem to be useful, because actually the number of lattice points in $RS^{d-1}$ is bounded by $R^{d-2+\epsilon}$. For d=3 the bound on $|T|$ is $R^{\epsilon}$

Comment: I misread your question... you wanted to know about the integral points on the sphere rather than the ball. Then you are right, indeed the bound I offer is not useful.